# How do I add a file upload field to user registration page?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I need to add a file upload field to user profile, during registration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In D7 all entities are field-able, and user profile fields can be manipulated in `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`

and in D6 you can use [content profile module](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile/)

Comment: Am using drupal6, So i triedwith Content profile module. But file uploading is not working in that module

Comment: do you get error on file field?

Comment: No error message, but the file is not getting uploaded.It simply refreshing the page when we click upload button